# Windows Server 2008 Standard, firewall disabled by Group Policy but ports are still filtered

Tags: windows-server-2008, centos, ping, snmp, nmap

Hihi,

So vanilla install of WS2008R2S, disabled FW with GP and trying grab SNMP with another host on the same subnet. The output of both if/ipconfig's and nmap -p 161 is below. Both machines running in VirtualBox with the connections bridged to the wireless adapter which is the only active connection on the host machine.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 192.168.11.122
PING 192.168.11.122 (192.168.11.122) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.11.122: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.50 ms
^C
--- 192.168.11.122 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 455ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.508/5.508/5.508/0.000 ms
[root@localhost ~]# nmap -p 161 192.168.11.122

Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-02-09 13:53 GMT
Nmap scan report for WIN-ERO1FIMO8N5.xxxxxxxx.com (192.168.11.122)
Host is up (0.00041s latency).
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
161/tcp filtered snmp
MAC Address: 08:00:27:E7:AA:E0 (Cadmus Computer Systems)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.30 seconds
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:E5:CD:BD
          inet addr:192.168.11.101  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fee5:cdbd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3784239 (3.6 MiB)  TX bytes:2109091 (2.0 MiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1301 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:142214 (138.8 KiB)  TX bytes:142214 (138.8 KiB)

[root@localhost ~]#





Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxxxxxx.com
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c82a:4a79:50bb:1832%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.11.122
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.11.200
```

Any ideas? :(

EDIT

Partial netstat output...

```
TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::]:49156             [::]:0                 LISTENING
TCP    [::]:49157             [::]:0                 LISTENING
UDP    0.0.0.0:161            *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*
UDP    192.168.11.122:137     *:*
UDP    192.168.11.122:138     *:*
UDP    [::]:161               *:*
UDP    [::]:500               *:*
UDP    [::]:4500              *:*
UDP    [::]:5355              *:*
```

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but did you enable any SNMP services?

Comment: Update, went back through the GP and re-checked all settings, firewall is definitely disabled and I'm not getting port closed instead of filtered. What's going on? :<

Comment: And yes, SNMP is enabled / configured. Will try it from another machine.

Comment: Where is GPO are you disabling the firewall? Computer Config -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Windows Firewall -> Windows Firewall -> Properties -> Firewall State?

Comment: Yes and it's showing as disabled and controlled by GP in the Windows Advanced Firewall GUI. Added partial netstat output to main post, hopefully will help.

Comment: Try a tcpdump/wireshark/capture on the client/server?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something very odd to do with the VirtualBox instance. No matter, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Did you explicitly allow SNMP service to allow packets from remote host IP address (Services, SNMP, properties, Security). It will only allow localhost by default.

Answer (score 1):

This post here will walk you through configuring the SNMP Service to your liking.

http://aaronwalrath.wordpress.com/2010/06/02/monitoring-windows-server-2008-r2-with-snmp-and-cacti/